# can TAB behave like M-i?

Tags: key-bindings, tab-key

I'm fairly new to aquamacs/emacs and while editing I noticed that it indents however it wants.
In order to indent the way I want I end up using M-i, but that is pretty cumbersome.
So, how do I make the TAB key behave like M-i (that is, inserting 4 spaces whenever I press it, regardless of the type of file I am editing)?

Comment: Basically, you want to bind the command that `M-i` calls to the `tab` key.  You can check what command that is with `C-h k M-i` (`describe-key`).  You can also have a look at how to bind keys in the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html) and on [Xah Lee's tutorial](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html).  Just a heads-up, though: a lot of packages and libraries make extensive use of the `tab` key for things other than indentation, so you may not want to overwrite those bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the command that is executed by `M-i`,

```
C-h k M-i
```

and bind it to `TAB`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") #'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

However, this will set the global binding, while you are most likely concerned with the binding of one or more global modes:

```
(add-hook c-mode-common-hook #'(lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "TAB" #'tab-to-tab-stop))))
```

But perhaps it would be better if you could describe what are your issues with Emacs' indentation (in a different question), so we can help you solve that.